# change the shape and randomly permutate an array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an array, which is of shape `(210000,64)`. I would like to transfer its shape to `(210000,64,1)` and moreover, I want to generate a new array, which is a random permutation of the original array along the dimension of `210000`.

Comment: `np.random.shuffle(array); array = array[:, None]`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Op wants a new array, so possibly create a new one with copy() at some point ?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ also, it should be `array[:, :, None]` or `array[..., None]`

Comment: @PaulPanzer oops, yes, thanks.

Comment: To create a new array: `array[np.random.permutation(array.shape[0]), :, None]`

Comment: slighly more expressive and self-documenting with `np.newaxis` instead of `None` or even better `np.expand_dims(array, axis=-1)`